# (IIS8.5)Microsoft Excel cannot open or save any more documents

Tags: excel, windows-server-2012, iis-8.5

**Microsoft Excel cannot open or save any more documents because there is not enough available memory or disk space. • To make more memory available, close workbooks or programs you no longer need. • To free disk space, delete files you no longer need from the disk you are saving to.**

I am getting this error while opening an excel sheet in my application
Application is running fine on `IIS5` and `IIS7` but when I shifted it to `Windows server 2012 R2` with `IIS8.5`  it didn't worked
I googled and found some solution but they also didn't worked.

**Here is what I have tried**

```
For both 32-bit and 64-bit versions of Windows, the folder “C:\Windows\System32\config
\systemprofile\desktop” must exist and you need Full Control permissions to the 
“systemprofile” and “desktop” directories.



For 64-bit versions of Windows 7 or Server 2008 and higher, the “C:\Windows\SysWOW64
\config\systemprofile\desktop” folder must also exist and you need Full Control
permissions to the “systemprofile” and “desktop” directories.



For 64-bit versions of Windows Vista, the “C:\Windows\SysWOW \config\systemprofile
\desktop” folder must also exist and you need Full Control permissions to the
 “systemprofile” and “desktop” directories.



For Windows 8.1, in addition to the above, the Windows Registry Key
 [HKEY_Current_User\Softwware\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\User Shell
 Folders\Cache] must be set to C:\Windows\Temp
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally found answer 
On 64 bit system with 32 bit Office try this:

```
Start
Run
mmc -32
File
Add Remove Snap-in
Component Services
Add
OK
Console Root
Component Services
Computers
My Computer
DCOM Config
Microsoft Excel Application
```

after finding excel application give it appropriate security clearance and you are good to go